# What is the difference between Serializer.PrepareSerializer and RuntTimeTypeModel.CompileInPlace

Tags: protobuf-net

Please correct me, to me it sounds like both Serializer.PrepareSerializer and RuntTimeTypeModel.CompileInPlace do the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They literally *are* the same thing:

in the generic `Serializer` API we have:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Precompiles the serializer for a given type.
    /// </summary>
    public static void PrepareSerializer<T>()
    {
        NonGeneric.PrepareSerializer(typeof(T));
    }
```

and in the non-generic `Serializer` API:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Precompiles the serializer for a given type.
    /// </summary>
    public static void PrepareSerializer(Type t)
    {
#if FEAT_COMPILER
        RuntimeTypeModel model = RuntimeTypeModel.Default;
        model[model.MapType(t)].CompileInPlace();
#endif
    }
```

The main difference here is that `PrepareSerializer` was a v1 API, and in v1 there was only one "model" (i.e. one set of runtime configuration data), and only one compilation mechanism. In v2, this expanded some - so the v1 API now just calls `CompileInPlace` on the *default* "model".

(`MapType` is something unrelated, that ties into some code that no longer exists; `MapType` has been removed completely in an unmerged branch)